# Strategies for proving propositional tautologies?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, algebra, boolean-expression, theorem-proving

Input is a string of symbols with (any) checked syntax and output is TRUE or FALSE.

My idea *was* post-fix representation of logical expressions written with AND, XOR and TRUE, but I finally realized that the patterns would be harder to recognize in post-fix.

Examples:

**p IMPLIES q** can be written **TRUE XOR p (XOR (p AND q))** abbreviated 1+p+pq

**p EQUIVALENT WITH q** can be written abbreviated 1+p+q

**NOT p** abbreviated 1+p

**p OR q** abbreviated p+q+pq

The rules in this *Boolean ring* is the same as in ordinary algebra, with the two rules

- p+p=0
- pp=p

and those rules, together with commutations, are responsible for all reductions, which will leads to '1' if the string correspond to a tautology. The tautology Modus ponens,

**((p IMPLIES q) AND p) IMPLIES q**,

should first be substituted as above, then expanded by multiplying distributively, and last repeatedly be simplified. A straightforward substitution of IMPLIES gives:

```
1+((1+f+fg)f)+((1+f+fg)f)g =
= 1+ f+ff+fgf +(f+ff+fgf)g =
= 1+ f+f+fg + fg+fg+fg =
= 1+ fg +fg+fg+fg = 1
```

When a tautological expression is written as an element in a Boolean ring it reduces mechanically to 1. Other expression reduces to a algebraically simpler expression.

Is this a good strategy? What strategies are used in computer science?

Comment: What you have suggested here is reminiscent of the very beginnings of boolean logic published in George Boole's "An Investigation of the Laws of Thought" in 1854. A fascinating read if you have the time.

Comment: Thanks! I found the book on http://www.gutenberg.org/files/15114/15114-pdf.pdf and will try to read it. Boolean rings, where every expression is put on the form with only AND and XOR, is very anti-intuitive for human thinking but extremely easy to reduce algebraically.

Comment: There's a way to determine whether a well-formed formula is a tautology in the freely downloadable program OTTER.  J. A. Kalman's book "Automated Reasoning with OTTER" hints at it around p. 342.  I can show you can an example OTTER input if you e-mail me at Lefelhocz2@yahoo.com

Comment: @Dough: Hi! I'm most interested in doing the program above and don't think propositional tautologies are hard to check. Mostly, I'm interested in what Boolean rings can do in logic, as in the book of Boole above. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in this [overview paper](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/1998/067/), an arbitrary propositional formula can be converted into *Conjunctive Normal Form* ([CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form)) in such a way that it has only polynomial larger size and is unsatisfiable iff the original formula was a tautology.

Practical tools for conversion from formula to CNF include [bool2cnf](http://www-ise4.ist.osaka-u.ac.jp/~t-tutiya/sources/bool2cnf/) and [bc2cnf](http://users.ics.aalto.fi/tjunttil/circuits/).

[SAT solvers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) for checking the unsatisfiability of the [CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) include [CryptoMiniSat](http://www.msoos.org/cryptominisat4/) and [Lingeling](http://fmv.jku.at/lingeling/).

See a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140990/verify-combinatorial-cnf-sat-encodings) which shows how to process propositional formulae using a SAT solver.

Comment: Thanks! Via CNF and Wikipedia I found ANF, algebraic normal form, which seems to be my approach.